# How to access a database initialized in a class from another class in python?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, web-applications

How would I go about implementing the MainPage class?

```
import cgi
import os
import logging

from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Greeting(db.Model):  #setting up database
  a = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  b = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  c = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  d = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
##I want to access the content of the database here which is defined in Downloader class. 
##For example let the value of greeting.a be assigned to alpha variable.   


#Entering data to the database
class Downloader(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting=Greeting()
        greeting.a=self.request.GET.get('a')
        greeting.b=self.request.GET.get('b')
        greeting.c=self.request.GET.get('c')
        greeting.d=self.request.GET.get('d')
        greeting.put()
```

Comment: This isn't possible because the self.request object is for a completely different webrequest object.  One possible solution is to have MainPage inherit Downloader.  Then, MainPage doesn't need a get() but it can be overridden.  If you want to override the get() method, but still call it, add the line 'Downloader.get(self)' to your code where it is applicable.

Comment: Instead of 'class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):' define the class as 'class MainPage(Downloader):'.  This also assumes that the Downloader class is in the same module as the MainPage.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to read the `Greeting` record that was written by the `Downloader` handler in a previous request?

Comment: Yes. This is basically what I am trying to do. Retrieve data from greeting database from MainPage class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by basically naming the database, and refer to it from another class

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a Downloader object to MainPage on initialization:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, downloader):
        self.downloader = downloader

    def get(self):
        self.downloader.get()
```

Comment: this is not working.. File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 685, in __call__
    handler = handler_class()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: In other words, `MainPage()` is being called instead of `MainPage(downloader)`.

Comment: What @Mike DeSimone said. Using this requires you to pass the downloader to the MainPage class when you initialize it.